# How to create these Bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, col

How do I create Bootstrap columns such as photo attached below? The red line is the same size?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) in the BS docs.  Also read about [Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

To answer your question more directly - here is what you need:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      1.1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      1.2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      1.3
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      2.1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          2.2T
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          2.2B
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      3.1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      3.2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      3.3
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          4.1T
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          4.1T
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      4.2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```